# Custom Actionbar optionButton not showing in Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have made a custom optionButton icon on the action bar. This worked fine but on my old tablet with android 4.4 only shows the standard icon.

I have set the icon with:

```
<style name="OptionButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/icon_option</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas how I can fix that?

**Edit:**

My Menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/donebutton"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/ud_menu_save"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchmenubutton"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title="search"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/anfordern"
    android:icon="@drawable/weather_edit_white"
    android:title="@string/basket_offerte" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:icon="@drawable/weather_edit_white"
    android:title="@string/basket_edit" />
</menu>
```

mipmapitems in project folder:

[image]

inflate option menu:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.basket_detail_option_menu,menu);
}
```

On simulator it works:
[image]

On my old tablet it doesn't work (show standard white icon):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this site to convert your image to different sizes :[romannurik.github.io](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

And add your images to Android studio `res` -> `mipmap` folder (one by one)

These are the different images size :

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

then use :

```
<style name="OptionButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
<item name="android:src">@mipmap/icon_option</item>
```

Change your xml to my xml code :

```
 <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/donebutton"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/ud_menu_save"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchmenubutton"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title="search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:visible="false" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/anfordern"
    android:icon="@drawable/weather_edit_white"
    android:title="@string/basket_offerte" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:icon="@drawable/weather_edit_white"
    android:title="@string/basket_edit" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I did it exactly as you described. But it will still show the standard icon on my old tablet (my phone, and Simulator show correctly) . can it be that with the androidversion 4.4 this is not possible or otherwise must be made?

Comment: Please attach xml code with Screensort of tab Appbar

Comment: This does not fix my problem. Now I have the text search next to the search icon. The options menu is still the white standard icon

Comment: if your are not able to solve this issue , then you can create a custom toolbar, it will be same as this and sure it will be same over all phones.

Comment: @ Abhishek kumar i have use a custom actionbar. actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom_layout_basket);
how can i set the optionmenu icon in this?

Comment: ahh toolbar and actionbar not the same ^^ but with this i must many change :-( but I will probably have no other choice..

Comment: change to toolbar surely it will work, if any doubt i'm here to help you @Andreas